# Source or derivation of recurring deposit formula

Tags: banking

The formula for calculating the maturity value of a recurring deposit is widely used by banks in India. The formula is based on quarterly compounding and is as follows:

Maturity value of RD; based on quarterly compounding: A = P * [(1 + r/4)^(4n - 1)] / (1 - (1 + r/4)^-1/3)

Where:

A = maturity amount (Rs.)
P = recurring deposit amount (Rs.)
r = interest rate per annum
n = number of quarters

The source of this formula is not clear. What is the source or how is this formula derived?

Comment: Looks like a finite-series simplification to me, though it's been a long time since that math class.  Write out the formula for the growth of each deposit and start refactoring...